# Add random values to table rows when saving data - mysql /laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have a table, there I want to save check list values where 12 types with releavant values to them.

ex:

type : 1  value :a

type : 2  value :c

type : 3  value :c

Likewise 12 types, so I want to add 1 to 12 values manually. How to proceed it with a loop?

Comment: How did you get the variables you're inserting in database?

Comment: @aldrin27 through service url

Comment: Can i see all data in your controller?

Comment: @aldrin27 : i have added it . pls check

Comment: What is the result if `echo count($find_shift)`?

Comment: @aldrin27 : 1 , count : 1

Comment: Where is the variable that will count dynamically to 12?

Comment: @aldrin27 : $pre_departure_type

Comment: @aldrin27 : pre_departure_type = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,

Comment: When you count `$pre_departure_type` it will get 12?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92119/discussion-between-faz-faz-and-aldrin27).

Comment: Sorry chat is blocked in my office. But am I right If you used `echo count($pre_departure_type);` it will get the result of 12?

Comment: @aldrin27  no im getting 1

Comment: @aldrin27  : 
this is how i recvie value from service url   user_id = 1
shift_id = 133
pre_departure_type = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

value = a,b,c,d,e,f
i want to save it inside table , each row have a same user_id , shift_id with matching departure types and values

Comment: So it will save 12 times?

Comment: @aldrin27 : thats wht im struggling. i want to add 1 to 12 for departre_type using a loop and get only values using service . pls advice

Comment: I've updated my answer. With explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
    //the code below is a string so explode it
    $pre_departure_type = $request->pre_departure_type;

   //exploded to array
    $arrayPreDepartureType = explode(',', $pre_departure_type);

    for($i = 0; i < count($arrayPreDepartureType); $i++){
     $DriverPreDepartureItems = new DriverPreDepartureItems();
     $DriverPreDepartureItems->user_id = $driver_id->id;

     $DriverPreDepartureItems->shift_id = $find_shift->id;
     // there are 10 departure types //
     $DriverPreDepartureItems->pre_departure_type = $arrayPreDepartureType[i];

     $DriverPreDepartureItems->value = $value;

     // there are 10 departure types //
     $DriverPreDepartureItems->save();
    }
    //It will save until it reaches the maximum count.
```